# Diferencias en palabras de género entre humanos y animales

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, género

En inglés tenemos ciertas palabras que se usa más a referirse al género de los humanos:

- man/woman
- boy/girl

Y no usamos esas palabras para referirse a animales. Para animales usaríamos más *male* y *female.*

En español tenemos palabras como *varón, hembra, macho, muchacho, muchacha, hombre, mujer, etc.* ¿Hay ciertos usos para esas palabras?

He escuchado de algunos que no debería usar *varón* ni *hembra* para los humanos, porque se usa esas palabras solo para animales. Pero yo sé que a veces las reglas son diferentes entre diferentes países, por eso quisiera saber lo que ustedes piensan.

Comment: A veces sí se usa _varón_ y _hembra_ para referirse a hombres y mujeres. Sin embargo, para mí tiene una connotación añadida de sobredimensionar el hecho de que sea hombre o mujer. Por ejemplo decimos "esa mujer es bellísima, es una santa hembra" (lo sé, es algo machista).

Comment: Yo creo que "varón" se puede usar sin problemas. "Macho" tiene otras connotaciones, según el contexto positivas o negativas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De todas las alternativas que mencionas, sólo *macho* y *hembra* pueden aplicarse a animales.

*varón*, *hombre*, *mujer*, *muchacho*, *muchacha* son exclusivas de los humanos.

Cuando *macho* y *hembra* se aplican a humanos suelen tener una connotación sexista.

Comment: Añadir que en la parte oriental de Cuba, macho se refiere al cerdo. `Ayer me comí un macho asado.` aunque se entiende por el contexto cuando se habla de una persona.

Answer (score 4):

En inglés *male* y *female* se usan tanto para humanos como para animales: *male dog*, *female tiger*, *male students*, *female teachers*... La regla en español es única: en español *macho* y *hembra* se utilizan casi exclusivamente para animales y cuando se hace en referencia a personas, suena despectivo, rudo y vulgar.

Por otra parte, el español incluye el género en la mayor parte de sus sustantivos. En términos humanos se utilizan las palabras *varón* y *mujer* y no *varón y hembra* como mencionan algunos. La única parte en donde se menciona la palabra *varona* es en antiguas traducciones bíblicas: "(...) *ella será llamada **Varona**, porque del varón fue tomada*" (Reina Valera 1909, Génesis 2, 22). Dicho uso curioso no trasciende y nadie dice *varones y varonas*, por lo tanto, el uso correcto es *varones y mujeres*. Entonces ¿*hombres y mujeres*? Es completamente correcto.

¿Ventajas y desventajas con el uso *varón* y *hombre*? Por esto el español es único en este caso. Si utilizo *hombres y mujeres* me refiero a personas adultas, pero cuando utilizo *varones y mujeres* o *varones y niñas*, entonces *varones* es versátil, lo que puede referir a un niño o a un adulto. Entonces ¿por qué utilizar la palabra *varón* si puedo hablar de niños y niñas, hombres y mujeres?

Esto nos hace concluir que la palabra *varón* tiene una connotación sexista exclusiva al género masculino y en la cual se quiere resaltar la condición masculina en cualquier situación. Por ejemplo *comportarse como todo un varón*, *demuestra que eres un varón*, *cosa de varones*... canciones como *El Gran Varón* de Willie Colón parodia las expectativas del padre por tener *un hijo varón* con la revelación de un hijo que termina siendo transgénero; en Milonga Sentimental de Carlos Gardel "*Varón, pa' quererte mucho, varón, pa' desearte el bien, varón, pa' olvidar agravios porque ya te perdoné*." El resaltar la valentía natural del varón frente al peligro, *como todo un varón*; en el Himno Nacional de Colombia la estrofa "*De Boyacá en los campos el genio de la gloria / con cada espiga un héroe invicto coronó. / Soldados sin coraza ganaron la victoria; / **su varonil aliento** de escudo les sirvió*." Joacim, Sumo Sacerdote en Jerusalén, felicita a Judit, una mujer, diciéndole: "*Porque te has portado **con varonil esfuerzo**, y has tenido un corazón constante; porque has amado la castidad y no has conocido a otro varón que a tu difunto marido* (...)" (Judit 15, 11).

¿Un homosexual se excluye de dicho concepto? Para muchos el término varón denota un sentido absoluto de comportamiento masculino y, por lo tanto, de natural preferencia por el sexo opuesto. Por ello les parece contradictorio referirse como varones a personas que prefieren a su mismo sexo. Pero si Judit se comporta *con varonil esfuerzo* siendo una mujer y sin por ello dejando de ser femenina, entonces el concepto varón nos habla más de fuerza, valentía, fortaleza de ánimo y no necesariamente actos exclusivos del género masculino como la preferencia por el sexo opuesto. Es pues correcto referirse a homosexuales como varones a menos que ellos mismos se sientan transgénero.